# Informatica: How to pick the sorted record from multiple rows or take the max on two columns together in Informatica

Tags: teradata, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement as below.

source:

```
   prod_id          DATE              Price      Count(Price)

   1          01-02-2017              100             1  

   1          01-02-2017              10             4          

   2          02-02-2017              50             1

   2          02-02-2017              60             1
```

I have data like this. Now I need to pick records with `max(count(Price))` for every unique `prod_id` and `date` combination, but if `Count(price)` is same then it should take `max(price)` or sort the columns on the basis of `Count(price)` and `price` and pick the top record. I'm achieving this data by using an aggregator doing `group by prod_id, date column` and taking `count` on `price` and not a direct table. How can I achieve this? Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Priyanka

Comment: I want records : for Prod_id: 1 ->Price:10 and for Prod_id:2 -> Price :60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the records based on Count(Price) and Price in that order and use an aggregator with prod_id and date as key. Do not use any aggregate function. The aggregator will pass the last record for each group.

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged Teradata, you can get it directly by adding

```
select .....
qualify
   row_number()
   over(partition by prod_id 
        order by Count(Price) desc, Price desc) = 1
```

to your current query.